# Issue showing image on UI when retrieve from outside of project

Tags: java, html, json

I have a Java project upload functionality which is uploading image onto the server location C:/temp and I want same image to show on UI as soon as uploaded but the problem is when i am passing image path(C:/temp) into JSON then then system is reading that image path relative to project and getting an error
(NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http:// localhost:8080/group/images/c:/temp/Jellyfish.jpg")
because file is present in C:/temp. What would be the possible solution of this. please help me guys?

Thanks,
Ankit

Answer (score 0):

You need a servlet that will read the file from `c:\temp`, and send the read bytes to the servlet's response output stream. You will also need to set the content type of the response to the mime type of image you're sending (`image/png` for example), and the content length to the number of bytes in the file.

And this is the URL of this servlet that you will have to pass into the JSON object.

Comment: Thanks JB. If u could share some examples of this type. That would have help great way for me.

Comment: what does this line means " this is the URL of this servlet ". 

Thanks

Comment: The JSON object that you send the URL must containg a URL allowing to get the image. This URL should be the URL of the servlet that you must create. For example: `http://my.host.com/imageServlet?imageFile=foobar.png`